# how the scale function in vector base draw app implement?

Tags: android, canvas, svg, vector-graphics, coordinate-systems

I am try to implement a hand-painted app by android (like infinite design ) 
and decide to use vector because it can scale and not distortion.

I think a lot and try to use the mode of viewport-horizon-world

- Viewport which rely on the sizeof phone (etc 1080*1920) it is the path you see and you touch
- Horizon the thing which will display on viewport
- World  the real coordinates of the point(which make up the path etc line
  ,bessel).

this model  works like

first you touch the screen of phone and **horizon will translate the point to the real world  coordinates** (if you move of scale) and save the value to world

second  you can move and scale by gestures it will **change the attribute of horizon** etc you move left 100 and down 100 the horizon will know now it  offset (100,100) and the bound will change  ((0,0),(1080,1920))->((100,100),(1180,2020))

last  when draw i find the path which include in horizon (calculate the bound of horizon and the bound of path) then **calculate the display coordinate rely on horizon**and draw the path by canvas.draw() etc

now the problem is when i just offset the horizon ,calculate the display coordinate just need to plus the offset values.but when scale it become difficult.for example  a path bound in ((0,0),(100,100)) and the horizon scale 0.5 in point (500,500) i don't know the position of the bound and don't know how to calculate the anchor of new path  the size and width(maybe just multiplied by the scale factor)

**the function i want to implement like the viewport in svg**
i think it should use  coordinate  mapping but how?
please give me some clue

Comment: use a Matrix class (from graphics package,  not opengl)

Comment: i need to calculate  the offset of each path to simulation real picture scale